# Each SLF4J log message contains a nested message

Tags: java, jboss, slf4j, jboss5.x

I use JBoss 5.2 and whenever I log something, slf4j outputs a nested log message, e.g.

```
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

...

logger.info("FOOBAR")
```

will result in the log message:

```
2015-06-11 09:54:37,154 INFO  [STDOUT] (quartzScheduler_Worker-1) 09:54:37,154 INFO  [MyClass] FOOBAR
```

The inner message is the correct one, why does the outer say that the logging class is STDOUT?

Non-project classes (library-classes) log messages look fine e.g,

```
2015-06-11 09:54:16,538 FINE  [javax.activation] (quartzScheduler_Worker-1) MailcapCommandMap: load DEF
```

Here is my log4j settings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">    
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
        <param name="File" value="server.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: jboss has its own logging configuration so you get jboss configuration appended before your configuration. You should amend jboss's log configuration instead of adding your own log4j settings files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by excluding JBoss version of slf4j. I still have multiple versions of SLF4J, but it seems to work.

```
2015-06-11 12:30:09,540 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

To exclude JBoss slf4 I created the file WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This site was very helpful http://ankitagarwal.com/wordpress/2012/05/20/using-your-own-instance-of-log4j-in-your-war-on-jboss-as-7-x-2/.